# How to get output from standard error in command line?

Tags: external-calls

I'm trying to run some external command line program in Mathematica, and I have problem getting the output.

For example,

```
Import["!echo hello world\nexit\n", "Text"]
(*"hello world"*)
```

run echo and get the output.

However this doesn't work for me

```
Import["!g++ -v", "Text"]
```

I only get an empty line.

In version 10, there is the `RunProcess` function which seems to work

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardError", "g++ -v
 exit
 "]

(*
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr \
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
*)
```

My question is, can we do the same thing in version 9, using other functions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under most operating systems you can use the `2>&1` handle redirection operator<sup>[(1)](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx),[(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Redirecting_to_and_from_the_standard_file_handles)</sup>:

```
Import["!foo 2>&1", "Text"]
```

> ```
> "'foo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file."
> ```

Comment: [Stream redirection is a UNIX thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Redirecting_to_and_from_the_standard_file_handles) so it should work on Linux and Mac OS X too. (I just checked on my Mac and it does indeed.)

Comment: @Rahul I am not at all surprised but I didn't know the syntax.  Would you consider adding a Mac example to my answer?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have been clearer: it's exactly the same syntax. I ran `Import["!g++ -v 2>&1", "Text"]` and got the G++ version information inside Mathematica.

Comment: Do you have any idea how redirection can be used with `RunProcess` instead of `Import`, `Run` or similar? I would like to use the nice facilities of `RunProcess` (like returning an association of exitcode, stdout, stderr), but am unable to figure out how to do it as nothing seems to work, e.g. `RunProcess[{"foo", "> file.out"}]`.

Comment: @István Sorry, I have not tried to do that and I don't wish to spend the time on it at the moment.  Perhaps next month I will feel more motivated.

Comment: Oh, no worries, there is of course no obliation to explore it : ) As a matter of fact, Tech Support just answered my question: `RunProcess[ $SystemShell, All, "foo > file.out" ]`.