# RunProcess with mdfind and -onlyin option

Tags: version-10, external-calls

I have problems running the bash code

```
mdfind -onlyin /some/folder my_string
```

This works on the terminal, but if I try

```
RunProcess[{"/usr/bin/mdfind", "-onlyin /some/folder", "my_string"}]
```

I get as an error

```
 Unknown option -onlyin /some/foder
```

While

```
RunProcess[{"/usr/bin/mdfind", "-onlyin", "/some/folder my_string"}]
```

gives as an error

```
/usr/bin/mdfind: no query specified
```

What is the correct way of handling this?

Comment: All the elements must be in separate items, this works for me : `RunProcess[{"mdfind", "-onlyin", "/some/folder", "my_string"}]` or `RunProcess[{"mdfind", "-onlyin", "/some/folder", "my_string"}, "StandardOutput"]` if you only need the standard output of the command, here the filenames.

Comment: Works for me thanks. You should expand it to an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found 3 ways to execute your command with `RunProcess` (on Unix like systems) :

Let's write your command as a string :

```
mycommand = "mdfind -onlyin /some/folder my_string";
```

but it could be any other command like :

```
mycommand = "ls -la";
```

Then these 3 inputs are equivalent :

```
RunProcess[StringSplit@mycommand]

RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "-c", mycommand}]

RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, mycommand <> "\nexit\n"]
```

In case you are just interested in the output not in the exit code nor error message, you just have to add/specify "StandardOutput" :

```
RunProcess[StringSplit@mycommand, "StandardOutput"]

RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "-c", mycommand}, "StandardOutput"]

RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardOutput", mycommand <> "\nexit\n"]
```

See also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59494/how-to-get-output-from-standard-error-in-command-line) and [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63174/how-to-trigger-unix-command-line-command-from-mathematica-notebook) posts for other useful approaches.